# How to convert text column to type described in another column?

Tags: postgresql, text, types, double

There is configuration table with key and value.

How to select records by comparing text value as integer or double?

```sql
create type val_enum as enum (
    'text',
    'integer',
    'double',
    'boolean',
    'date'
);

create table conf (
    id      serial primary key,
    name    varchar(16),
    val     varchar(16),
    val_en  val_enum
);
```

example table:

```
id  name    val     val_en
--------------------------- 
1   age     34      integer
2   name    john    text
3   male    true    boolean
4   weight  71.2    double  

select *
from conf
where (name = 'weight') and 
      (val::val_en > 70) ???
```

Comment: Try this https://dbfiddle.uk/IEzgdr55

Answer (score 0):

Converting text to a type then comparing it is not realistic in SQL because the comparison won't be valid for all result types.

If you have text, you must use a text approach:

```
select *
from conf
where name = 'weight'
and val regexp_like '^([0-9]{3}|[8-9][0-9]|7[1-9]|70.*[1-9])'
```

That regex matches any number greater than 70.

The regex would have been a lot simpler if your comparison operator was `>=` instead of `>`

Comment: Works for me https://dbfiddle.uk/IEzgdr55